# Running a large query in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, large-files, large-data

I need to grab rows in a database which contain an item that matches any of 175,000 items and convert the results into a csv file (which I will later parse and analyze with python script).  Some issues that come to mind are: [can u actually input that large a list of items into a workbench sql query (there is not enough memory to copy it)? would the network support such a large data transfer?  other things I don't know?]  What would be a smart way to query and fetch this large amount of data?  I am using MySql Workbench on windows to a windows server, but am open to trying a better interface option.

Simple (but not practical in this case) query format:

```
select * from database where date>='2017-06-01 00:00:00' and date<='2017-07-01 00:00:00' and instr in ('ab123', 'azx0456', 'rtpz888')
```

*there should be about 10,000,000 records (or rows) between those two specified dates.
*the "instr in (...)" part actually would require a list of about 175,000 unique items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. import the instr filter into a separate table, for example table xx, column name instr
2. `select * from database where date>='2017-06-01 00:00:00' and date<='2017-07-01 00:00:00' and instr in (select instr from xx)`

I have not really using sql for a while. This should be fine. 
the exporting part `select * from database into outfile "aa.txt" where ....`

Comment: A join might be fun

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but there's one problem: I have never created/edited anything in a database.  I will try this way, but in doing so, must learn how to properly create this new, separate table and then hopefully it all works together.  I will let you know how it worked out